# How to partition this into a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to refactor my code so that it follows good OO pattern, which is reusability and less repetition.. I have the following code:

```
 PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Vote"];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
    [query whereKey:@"poll" equalTo:self.vote];
    [query whereKey:@"note" notEqualTo:nil];
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError * error) {
        note = number;
        [self.noteCount addSubview:self.generateCountLabel];

        if (note > 0){
            [self.note setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [self.note setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }];

    PFQuery * query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Vote"];
    query1.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
    [query1 whereKey:@"poll" equalTo:self.vote];
    [query1 whereKey:@"image" notEqualTo:nil];
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError * error) {
        pic = number;    
        [self.picCount addSubview:self.generateCountLabel];

        if (pic > 0){
            [self.pic setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [self.pic setEnabled:YES];
        }

    }];
```

Found it really difficult to partition into one method without doing a lot of if's. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the following method....

```
- (void)queryForKey:(NSString *)aKey view:(UIView *)aView countView:(UIView *)aCountView  {
    PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Vote"];        
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
    [query whereKey:@"poll" equalTo:self.vote];
    [query whereKey:aKey notEqualTo:nil];
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError * error) {
        count = number;    
        [aCountView addSubview:self.generateCountLabel];

        if (count > 0){
            [aView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [aView setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }];
}
```

Then you can call...

```
[self queryForKey:@"note" view:self.note countView:self.noteCount];
[self queryForKey:@"image" view:self.pic countView:self.picCount];
```

If you firm up your naming you can use dynamic object selectors, i.e. for the 'note' one you have @"note", self.note and self.noteCount so you could take the @"note" and select both the note and noteCount views dynamically (as they both start with 'note'), however this wouldn't work for your image one as you have @"image" but then self.pic and self.picCount.

**UPDATE**

Rename image to pic and then expose the four views (picCount, pic, note and noteCount) as properties. Then you can use something like this...

```
- (void)queryForKey:(NSString *)aKey  {
    PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Vote"];        
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
    [query whereKey:@"poll" equalTo:self.vote];
    [query whereKey:aKey notEqualTo:nil];
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError * error, NSString *aKey) {
        [self setValue:number forKey:aKey];
        UIView *countView = [self objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Count", aKey]];
        [countView addSubview:self.generateCountLabel];

        if (number > 0){
            UIView *mainView = [self objectForKey:aKey];
            [mainView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [mainView setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }];
}
```

You will have to play around with it as I don't have your full class definition to get it exactly right.

Comment: can you give me an example of doing this dynamically if I were to change the name as well from image to pic

Comment: you're syntax is also messed up, what is count here? it's not defined in the method signature, query1 and query is conflicting

Comment: also count is an int, and I don't see it anywhere in your function signature.. I did try to add count as an parameter and assign it, but it doesn't work

Comment: and what if I can't pass in aKey as a block parameter, will that still work?